# Sitecore.Context.Item added to Dependency Injection not working when needed by secodary DI'ed class

Tags: dependency-injection

I need to get the context item to create a "SearchContext" in my repository class using the following configurator :

```
public class DependencyInjectionConfigurator : IServicesConfigurator
{
    public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<Item>(m => Sitecore.Context.Item ??
            Sitecore.Context.Database
           .GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Site.StartPath));
    }
}
```

The example class is used in a pipeline and is pretty basic:

```
public class Example
{
    public Example(Item contextItem)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'Example' while attempting to activate 'CustomHttpRequestProcessor'.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Example' while attempting to activate 'CustomHttpRequestProcessor'.]
```

I should mention I set `resolve=true` in the configuration

Comment: Remember in a pipeline/processor you need to set the attribute `Resolve="true"`. If you already did that, please update your question.

Comment: yep, already did that.

Comment: just checking.. Added the relevant config to register this.?

Comment: yep /Sitecore/Services/Register and /Sitecore/Services/Configurator tags are all there

Comment: Can you see your registration in http://[instance]/sitecore/admin/showservicesconfig.aspx?